# Python tkinter: Creating a task bar in a popup window

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, popupwindow

I'm learning how to use tkinter, and I'm making a user interface where one of my functions is expected to take a longer time to execute (~20s), so I want to create a progress bar that pops up in a separate window whenever the function is executing and then automatically goes away when the function is finished executing.

Below is the code that I have so far.  When I execute it, I get the main tk window with the "Do Task" button, but when I click the button, calling the `do_task(self)` function, the progress bar starts at 0%, and then I get an error message
referring to line 53 in `increment_progressbar`, the line which reads "`if pb['value'] <= 100*(N-1)/N:`"

The error message is:

```
\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1652, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel2.!progressbar"
```

I've also tried declaring "`global pbwindow`" and "`global pb`" before the definitions of pbwindow and pb in the `open_progressbar(self)` function definition, but when I do this I don't see the progress bar at all.

How do I make this work so that I can see the progress bar progressing every 2 seconds?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import time

class Progress_GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='Do Task', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.do_task)
        self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def do_task(self):
        
        def update_progress(pb):
            return 'Current Progress: {}%'.format(pb['value'])
        
        def open_progressbar(self):
            
            pbwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            pbwindow.geometry('300x120')
            pbwindow.title('Task in Progress')
            
            pbwindow.label = tk.Label(pbwindow, text='Doing Task', font=('Arial', 12))
            pbwindow.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            pb = tk.ttk.Progressbar(pbwindow, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
            pb.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            pbwindow.valuelabel = tk.Label(pbwindow, text=update_progress(pb), font=('Arial',12))
            pbwindow.valuelabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
        def increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N):
            if pb['value'] <= 100*(N-1)/N:
                pb['value'] += 100/N
                pbwindow.valuelabel['text'] = update_progress(pb)
        
        def close_progressbar(pbwindow):
            pbwindow.destroy()
            
        def task(N):
            
            open_progressbar(self)
            
            for n in range(round(N)):
                time.sleep(2)
                
                increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N)
                
            time.sleep(2)
            
            close_progressbar(pbwindow)
            
        task(10)
            
    
Progress_GUI()
```

**Edit**: It seems that threading is somehow key to solving this problem.  For example, when I execute the following code, the window with the task bar does not appear at all:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class Progress_GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='Do Task', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.do_task)
        self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def do_task(self):
        
        def update_progress(pb):
            return 'Current Progress: {}%'.format(pb['value'])
        
        def open_progressbar(self):
            
            global pbwindow
            pbwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            pbwindow.geometry('300x120')
            pbwindow.title('Task in Progress')
            
            pbwindow.label = tk.Label(pbwindow, text='Doing Task', font=('Arial', 12))
            pbwindow.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            global pb
            pb = tk.ttk.Progressbar(pbwindow, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
            pb.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            pbwindow.valuelabel = tk.Label(pbwindow, text=update_progress(pb), font=('Arial',12))
            pbwindow.valuelabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
        def increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N):
            if pb['value'] <= 100*(N-1)/N:
                pb['value'] += 100/N
                pbwindow.valuelabel['text'] = update_progress(pb)
        
        def close_progressbar(pbwindow):
            pbwindow.destroy()
            
        def task(N):
            
            open_progressbar(self)
            
            for n in range(round(N)):
                time.sleep(2)
                
                increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N)
                
            time.sleep(2)
            
            close_progressbar(pbwindow)
            
        task(10)
            
    
Progress_GUI()
```

However, the following code does work:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class Progress_GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='Do Task', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.do_task)
        self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def do_task(self):
        
        def update_progress(pb):
            return 'Current Progress: {}%'.format(pb['value'])
        
        def open_progressbar(self):
            
            global pbwindow
            pbwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            pbwindow.geometry('300x120')
            pbwindow.title('Task in Progress')
            
            pbwindow.label = tk.Label(pbwindow, text='Doing Task', font=('Arial', 12))
            pbwindow.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            global pb
            pb = tk.ttk.Progressbar(pbwindow, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
            pb.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            pbwindow.valuelabel = tk.Label(pbwindow, text=update_progress(pb), font=('Arial',12))
            pbwindow.valuelabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
        def increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N):
            if pb['value'] <= 100*(N-1)/N:
                pb['value'] += 100/N
                pbwindow.valuelabel['text'] = update_progress(pb)
        
        def close_progressbar(pbwindow):
            pbwindow.destroy()
            
        def task(N):
            
            open_progressbar(self)
            
            for n in range(round(N)):
                time.sleep(2)
                
                increment_progressbar(pbwindow, pb, N)
                
            time.sleep(2)
            
            close_progressbar(pbwindow)
            
        threading.Thread(target=task, args=(10,)).start()
            
    
Progress_GUI()
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading
import time

class Progress_GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='Do Task', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.do_task)
        self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def do_task(self):
        def update_progress(pb):
            return 'Current Progress: {}%'.format(pb['value'])
        
        def open_progressbar():
            self.pbwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            self.pbwindow.geometry('300x120')
            self.pbwindow.title('Task in Progress')
            
            self.pbwindow.label = tk.Label(self.pbwindow, text='Doing Task', font=('Arial', 12))
            self.pbwindow.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.pbwindow, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
            self.pb.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            self.pbwindow.valuelabel = tk.Label(self.pbwindow, text=update_progress(self.pb), font=('Arial',12))
            self.pbwindow.valuelabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            self.pbwindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: 0) # not able to close the pop
        
        def increment_progressbar(N):
            if self.pb['value'] <= 100*(N-1)/N:
                self.pb['value'] += 100/N
                self.pbwindow.valuelabel['text'] = update_progress(self.pb)
        
        def close_progressbar():
            self.pbwindow.destroy()
        
        def task(N):
            self.button1.config(state="disabled")
            open_progressbar()
            
            for n in range(round(N)):
                time.sleep(2)
                increment_progressbar(N)
            
            time.sleep(2)
            close_progressbar()
            self.button1.config(state="normal")

        
        threading.Thread(target=task, args=(10,)).start()
    
Progress_GUI()
```

---

1. The `pbwindow` and `pb` variables have been made instance variables (`self.pbwindow` and `self.pb`) to avoid the issue of the progress bar not being found.
2. The `open_progressbar`, `increment_progressbar`, and `close_progressbar` functions have been modified to use the instance variables accordingly.
3. The `task` function is now executed in a separate thread using the `threading.Thread` class to prevent blocking the main GUI thread.

**Comment if you have any problem or want more explanation.**
[image]

Comment: Why is it necessary to make all of these into instance variables?  Why don't I see the progress bar at all if I declare pbwindow and pb as global variables?

Comment: Why is threading necessary?  I want to avoid threading because the actual function that I'm tracking returns an array at the end and I want to access the array later in my code.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over many responses to similar questions, I finally found a way to make this work without threading.  The key is to store the value for the progress bar in a holder created with `tk.DoubleVar()`, and then to call the `update()` function in your loop to make sure that the progress bar actually moves.  The following code gives the desired result:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

class Progress_GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='Do Task', font=('Arial', 18), command=self.do_task)
        self.button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def do_task(self):
        def update_progress(pbwindow):
            return 'Current Progress: {}%'.format(pbwindow.progress)
        
        def open_progressbar(self):
            global pbwindow
            pbwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
            pbwindow.geometry('300x120')
            pbwindow.title('Task in Progress')
            
            pbwindow.label = tk.Label(pbwindow, text='Doing Task', font=('Arial',12))
            pbwindow.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
            pbwindow.progress = 0
            pbwindow.progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
            
            pbwindow.pb = ttk.Progressbar(pbwindow, variable=pbwindow.progress_var, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
            pbwindow.pb.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
                        
            pbwindow.valuelabel = tk.Label(pbwindow, text=update_progress(pbwindow), font=('Arial', 12))
            pbwindow.valuelabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            
        def increment_progressbar(pbwindow, N):
            pbwindow.progress += 100/N
            pbwindow.progress_var.set(pbwindow.progress)
            pbwindow.valuelabel['text'] = update_progress(pbwindow)
                
        def close_progressbar(pbwindow):
            pbwindow.destroy()
            
        def task(N):
            
            open_progressbar(self)
            for n in range(round(N)):
                pbwindow.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                increment_progressbar(pbwindow, N)
            
            pbwindow.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            
            close_progressbar(pbwindow)
            
        task(10)        
        
        
Progress_GUI()
```